# Controls inside LoginView don't get added to designer file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-identity

Ok,

I'm working on a C# WebForms project and using a LoginView control on the Default page.  Any controls created at design time inside the "LoginView" do not get created in the designer.cs file and thus are not available in the codebehind.  Is this by design?  I checked this with just a basic "Web Forms Project" in both VS 2013 and VS 2015.  For anything I want to have codebehind access it seems I need to use the LoginView.FindControl method. It seems to wire up events for those controls just fine.

Is this by design?  I don't see anything in the LoginView's documentation that explains this.

Comment: There is no much in ***LoginView*** - ***LoggedInTemplate***, ***AnonymousTemplate*** and ***RoleGroups***. What would like to achieve?

Comment: The whole point of the LoginView is to have content that displays depending on the Users Authentication.  I have a gridview and other controls inside the <LoggedInTemplate>.

Comment: ***LoginView*** is meant for small controls like displaying User's Name. It is never meant to show/hide data controls like ***GridView***.

Comment: Win, does it say that anywhere in the documentation?  If this is by design I can accept that but it would be nice if that was documented somewhere.  The examples on MSDN give the controls inside each template an ID which infers that you have codebehind access to them.

Comment: I wasted a whole day tracking this one down. There are zillions of posts about why controls don't show up in the designer file and I tried a whole bunch of workarounds before I found this. Anyway it is a doddle to create a session variable which gets set to true when your user logs in and false when they log out. You can then use a simple IF statement in your aspx page to do what the LoginView control does, but without losing sight of all the controls on your page.